# Sheet 1 - Variable is not defined

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that worked but now is giving me variable is not defined and after click on debug it marks me Sheet1. I checked microsoft runntime scripting and I dont know where is the problem. I know that this code is good because before everything worked. Any ideas?

Note: Before the sub recurse () is the get data function with option explicit.

```
Sub Recurse()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder, mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
 Dim myFile As File
Dim sPath$: sPath = "C:\Users\Miruška\Desktop\skuska\"
Dim R$
R = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange), "|")
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
    DoEvents
    If Not (InStr(1, R, myFile.Path) > 0) Then
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "F1:F2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "O4:O5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)), True, False
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "AH1:AH2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)), True, False
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = myFile.Path
        R = R & myFile.Path & "|"
    End If
Next
Next
Set FSO = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set mySubFolder = Nothing
Set myFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: change `Sheet1` to `Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: you might have change the property name of the sheet `Sheet1`. Check again all the names if it is still the same as before. There might be occassions wherein you deleted sheets or other same scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from "Sheet1" to reference the object name Sheet1 - or use the Sheets collection Sheets("Sheet1")

```
GetData myFile, Sheets("Sheet1"), "F1:F2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False
```